# Email settings queries on Django

Tags: django, django-settings

I have the following codes in settings.py for email:

```
#SMTP Configuration

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

I just learnt about this email system from the guide - https://www.youtube.com/watchv=sFPcd6myZrY.

In the video, it is stated as not secure as he key in his password but blocked it off. How do I hide this part? From the source code this user post in Github, it is `********` for the user and password. I assume that is his details but it is hidden. How do I do the same for my details?

Comment: You should use environment variables like `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("DJANGO_MAIL_PASSWORD", "")`

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution @Marco, but how do I use this? I read in other post that some suggest this also but never specific on how to use this. From what I understand, the codes I posted is needed with the account details for User and Password. If i where to replace the last line with the provided solution, where do I declare the password?

Comment: Setting environment variables depends on the OS you use. I recommend you using always a virtual environment. Then you can set your environment variables inside this virtual env. A good starting point could be [How to Set and Get Environment Variables in Python](https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5)